# Null pointer exception in Android Play Publisher plugin Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to setup continuous delivery for Android application using Jenkins in EC2 instance.

I am getting following error stack trace during apk upload without any messages.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:82)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkUploadTask.execute(ApkUploadTask.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.AbstractPublisherTask.call(AbstractPublisherTask.java:33)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1161)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.publishApk(ApkPublisher.java:375)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.googleplayandroidpublisher.ApkPublisher.perform(ApkPublisher.java:195)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

I had a look at the source code and could figure out that plugin is failing at reading current version codes of existing apks from console. I have given all the accesses for service account which is trying to access this api.

```
// Get the list of existing APKs and their info
    final List<Apk> existingApks = editService.apks().list(applicationId, editId).execute().getApks();
    for (Apk apk : existingApks) {
        existingVersionCodes.add(apk.getVersionCode());
    }
```

So I am getting existing apks null, does anyone ever faced same issue.

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-play-android-publisher-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/googleplayandroidpublisher/ApkPublisher.java

Comment: @AbhinavGupta ??